# Compute eigenvalue of a $4\times4$ matrix with all entries $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix, call it A:
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
I need to find its eigenvalue using its characteristic polynomial. I already did this on smaller matrices which were comfortable to calculate.
But calculating an eigenvalue for this matrix seems too complex - Possibly there's a better method?

Edit: This needs to be done without an external help (e.g. Wolfram Alpha).

Comment: Are you sure you want to find the eigenvalues using the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: enter modern world: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Comment: but this is a symmetric rank one matrix so it has three eigenvalues zero and one equal to the trace of this matrix.

Comment: more: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=characteristic+polynomial+%7B%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier method: note that this is a symmetric rank one matrix.  In fact, let $x = (1,1,1,1)^T \in \Bbb R^4$.  Note that $A = xx^T$.

What does the kernel of $A$ look like?  What does this tell you about its eigenvalues?

Alternatively: note that $Ay = x(x^Ty) = \langle y,x \rangle x$.  Perhaps you can use this to deduce the eigenvectors of $A$ directly.

Alternatively: let $u_1 = \frac 12 x$, which has length $1$.  Extend $u_1$ to an orthonormal basis $u_1,\dots,u_4$.  Let $U$ be the matrix whose columns are these vectors.  Note that
$$
A = U\pmatrix{4\\&0\\&&0\\&&&0}U^T
$$

Comment: The kernel of A has dimension 3... It doesn't tell me anything about its eigenvalue :/

Comment: @Dor yes it does.  It tells you that $A$ has the eigenvalue $0$ with geometric multiplicity $3$.  What else could we deduce, using perhaps the fact that $A$ is symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

Set $x = (1, 1,1,1)^\top$, so that $A= xx^\top$. Then 
$$ \det(A - \lambda I) = (-\lambda)^4 \det(I - xx^\top/\lambda).$$
By [Sylvester's Determinant Theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_determinant_theorem), this equals 
$$(-\lambda)^4 \det(I - x^\top x/\lambda) = (-\lambda)^4 (1-4/\lambda) = \lambda^3(\lambda-4). $$
From there, you're home free.